# CPLEX OPL Error 5002: Constraint not convex continues even setting optimalitytarget=3

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a problem with CPLEX Optimization Studio. I want to solve the following quadratic constraint problem, but I get 'CPLEX Error  5002: 'qconstraint1' is not convex.->'. Inicially I thought it was because the optimalitytarget is not automatically set to 3, but even when I set that explicitly the error continues. An interesting fact is that the problem is solved normally in AMPL or MATLAB environment.

How can I solve this problem?

```
/*********************************************
 * OPL 12.10.0.0 Model
 * Author: johnm
 * Creation Date: Oct 16, 2020 at 6:29:33 PM
 *********************************************/
execute{
  cplex.optimalitytarget=3;
}
range R=1..6;
dvar float x[R];

minimize x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] + x[6];
subject to{
  constraint1: x[1] +  x[2] + x[5] == 8;
  constraint2: x[3] + x[5] + x[6] == 10;
  qconstraint1: -x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3]^2 <= 0;
  qconstraint2: -x[4]^2 + x[5]^2 <= 0;
  bound_x1:   x[1] >= 0;
  bound_x4:   x[4] >= 0;
  bound_x6:   x[6] >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
execute{
  cplex.optimalitytarget=3;
}
range R=1..6;
dvar float x[R] in 0..100;

minimize x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] + x[6];
subject to{
  constraint1: x[1] +  x[2] + x[5] == 8;
  constraint2: x[3] + x[5] + x[6] == 10;
  qconstraint1: x[1]^2 - x[2]^2 - x[3]^2 >= 0;
  qconstraint2: -x[4]^2 + x[5]^2 <= 0;
  bound_x1:   x[1] >= 0;
  bound_x4:   x[4] >= 0;
  bound_x6:   x[6] >= 0;
}
```

works fine

Comment: Thanks a lot. The declaration "dvar float x[R] in 0..100" solves the problem, but its important indicate that this declaration does not allow negative variables and when I solved the same problem with AMPL I get one negative variable:                               CPLEX 12.10.0.0: Version identifier: 12.10.0.0 | 2019-11-26 | 843d4de2ae
optimal solution; objective 18
5 barrier iterations
No basis.
x1 = 4.94145
x2 = -0.00182345
x3 = 1.37674

x4 = 3.06037
x5 = 3.06037
x6 = 5.56289